# How do I install python package tobii_research?

Tags: python, macos, installation, import

I am trying to install tobii_research for a project and I was following the instructions on http://developer.tobiipro.com/python/python-getting-started.html

I already have python 3.7.6 and pip 21.1.2 installed on my Mac.

When I run `pip install tobii-research` I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tobii_research (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tobii-research
```

Was there something I forgot to install?

I can not for the life of me figure out how to install this manually either.
Help with pip, or installing manually would be greatly appreciated, but you might have to explain it to me like I am stupid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a typo on their developer documentation page. See https://pypi.org/project/tobii-research/

Comment: try with `pip3` instead of pip

Comment: pip3 didn't work. I tried 'pip install tobii-research' as well

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not running the correct python version for the versions of the package that are available.  If you look at the wheel files available on the tobii-research Downloads page, the software is packaged for either python 2.7 or 3.6.

When trying to install this package myself, I get the same error message as you when trying to install it for python 3.8, but the package installs successfully with my python 2.7 installation.

I would recommend installing a compatible version of python and then running pip through that version using the following command:

`[specific_python_installation] -m pip install tobii-research`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with pip again, but replace the underscore with a hyphen as shown below:

`pip install tobii-research`

Comment: I did that one too. I copied from: https://pypi.org/project/tobii-research/

Comment: Are you using pycharm as your IDE? If so, go to File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter and select your current project you want to install tobii-research in. Then, click the plus icon and search for tobii-research. When it comes up, install it.

Comment: I couldn't find tobii-research there.

Comment: Are you sure you have python set as your interpreter? On Pycharm, go to File > Settings > Project > Project interpreter and in that tab does it say that the python interpreter is set to Python 3.9?

Answer (score 0):

I saw on the [PyPi website](https://pypi.org/project/tobii-research/#files) that  they only have it for Python 3.8, so I downloaded that Python version from their [official website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/) and installed it (do not add it to path).

Then, I created a virtual environment selecting 3.8 as the Python version (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544)) and activated that virtual environment.

Finally, I run `pip install tobii_research` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped me - required Python version. For example, for the  version `1.10.2` (which is current at the moment of writing this) only Python 3.10 is supported. Check the [list of files](https://pypi.org/project/tobii-research/1.10.2/#files) distributed within this version.

I was able to install the package on Windows with Python 3.10 but on MacOS I had the same problem and wasn't able to resolve this - I assume it's a problem with the architecture, as there is no version for `arm64` if you have a Mac with M1 processor.